# User.IsInRole returns false for one group but not another

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm in these two AD groups: Group1, Group2. Why would this same code return false for Group1 and true for Group2 when I'm in both groups?

```
var user = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
if (!user.IsInRole(groupName)) { return false; }
```

When I check with a third-party AD tool, I can see that I'm in both groups. [I've seen that there are issues with the administrator role](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2677673/279516), but I'm just checking two normal AD groups. I'm not sure where to start figuring out why one returns false and the other returns true.

This completely different approach works:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "foo.bar:389", "dc=foo,dc=bar", "account", "pw");

using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, principal.Identity.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName));  // RETURNS TRUE
}
```

**EDIT**

I used a free AD tool to try and spot some differences between the two groups. The only real thing I found is that the parent containers are different. Could this have anything to do with the issue?

Parent Container
Group 1: Security Groups/NonLocationSpecific/domain.LOCAL
Group 2: CityName/Security Groups/NonLocationSpecific/domain.LOCAL

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in , what does the PrestoUser.Groups property show?

Comment: Is your AD account in a group that is part of group1? If so, you will need to search recursively.

Comment: @ChrisBint I see PrestoUser.Identity.WindowsIdentity.Groups. There are 159 of them, and all I see are a bunch of Sids.

Comment: @BillSambrone No, my AD account is directly a member of both groups.

Comment: Is Group1 the "Primary Group" for that user?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain How do I tell that?

Comment: It is [at the bottom the "Member Of" tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vPyfA.png) when you are viewing the user's info. A screenshot of that screen would actually be very helpful for us to answer your question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't have access to that. I can email our service desk to see if they can give me that info. That will take some time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Group1 is not the primary group for that user.

Comment: Can you open your command prompt and do `NET USERS username /domain` and copy and paste the group memberships section here.

Comment: I don't think my company would like me to paste that info. But I did run it and both groups show up under the Global Group memberships section.