# How can I prevent my program from running if it is not ran in Administrative mode? XP and Windows 7

Tags: c#, security, admin

I have a C# Program that is supposed to be multi-OS compatible. It requires access to create a directory and get WMI Data, but that is only available if the program is ran as an Administrator. Otherwise, it fails.

Is there any command I can use to not run the program if it does not detect itself as being ran as an administrator? I tried adding a app.manifest and using "requireAdministrator", it prompts for login, but that appears to only work on Windows 7 and Vista, not XP.

Example:

```
 if (isAdmin==0)
 Console.WriteLine("Please run this as an administrator");
 exit;
```

Comment: Why dont you create the folder in the AppData ?

Comment: I belive you can find your answer here 
    http://stackoverflow.com/q/1089046/1108627

Comment: Having an admin account is no guarantee that you can delete files.  Even less so on Vista and up.  By far the simplest and most reliable way is to just catch the UnauthorizedAccessException and call it quits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In .NET/C# test if process has administrative privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-process-has-administrative-privileges)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Check if the User Is an Admin

```
public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);

    return windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

### Restart the app if not an admin

```
public static bool RestartAsAdministrator(string filePath, string fileName, string errorCaption)
{
    Process process = null;
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 5) //5 is XP and 6 is Vista and 7
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

    processStartInfo.Arguments = "";
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    try
    {
        process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't start as admin.\nPlease try manually by Right Clicking on " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + " and selecting \"Run as administrator\"",
                            errorCaption + " Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        return false;
    }

    finally
    {
        if (process != null)
            process.Dispose();
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Application Manifest File (Used to automatically Run as Admin)

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function to check if the current user (that starts your application) has administrator rights.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
...
bool IsAnAdministrator ()
{
   WindowsIdentity  identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
   WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal (identity);
   return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

If you call this method and it returns `false` you can show a message and/or close your application.