# Detect if user is administrator in Windows 8 with c#

Tags: c#, authorization, windows-8

I have some code that works in most versions of windows to detect if the current user is running as administrator.  I have seen issues where our customers use group policies and this doesn't work.  Now I have upgraded my workstation to Windows 8 and the code no longer works.  Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
private static extern int LogonUser(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
private const int Logon32LogonInteractive = 2;
private const int Logon32ProviderDefault = 0;

public void Run() {
    var _token;    
    LogonUser(Username, Domain, Password, Logon32LogonInteractive, Logon32ProviderDefault, ref _token);
     _windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(_token);
     WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(_windowsIdentity);
     var isAdmin = myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

In this case, isAdmin is false when it should be true.  If anyone knows the correct way to do this check that will work in all versions of windows, that would be great.  Even better if someone knows how to change this code so that it works in a domain with group policies in use.

I tried to copy the appropriate code from my class.  Obviously this will not compile but if I missed something let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You trying to write "one" solution is not wise, because its not possible, mainly because even between Vista and 7 the method will be different.  Write solutions directed towards each operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work if UAC is enabled on Windows Vista and later. To [quote the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsbuiltinrole):

> **Note:** In Windows Vista, User Account Control (UAC) determines the privileges of a
>   user. If you are a member of the Built-in Administrators group, you are assigned two
>   run-time access tokens: a standard user access token and an administrator access token.
>   By default, you are in the standard user role. When you attempt to perform a task that
>   requires administrative privileges, you can dynamically elevate your role by using the
>   Consent dialog box. The code that executes the IsInRole method does not display the
>   Consent dialog box. The code returns false if you are in the standard user role, even if
>   you are in the Built-in Administrators group. You can elevate your privileges before you
>   execute the code by right-clicking the application icon and indicating that you want to
>   run as an administrator.

`isAdmin` will be false unless the user is running elevated. You might see this question: [In .NET/C# test if process has administrative privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-user-is-an-administrative-user) for more.

You might try using imperative or declarative **security demands** for the specific things you want to do rather than checking group membership. These will throw a SecurityException if you lack the demanded permissions, which you can trap and then deal with.

Answer (score 0):

try changing Logon32LogonInteractive value to 3 - which is NETWORK_LOGON