# Check if user is a local admin on external machine

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, security

I'm writing an app that aggregates all the event log entries on each of several different servers.  I can get the event logs by passing in the `MachineName` to `EventLog.GetEventLogs`.  This will typically fail at some stage is the user is not a local administrator on that machine, so I'd like to check for it ahead of time and skip to the next set of servers if that is the case

```vb
For Each svr As String In Servers

    'TODO: check to see if they are a local administrator, else continue for

    Dim logs As List(Of EventLog) = EventLog.GetEventLogs(svr).ToList
    For Each log As EventLog In logs
        LoadEachOSLogEntry(log)
    Next
Next
```

Most solutions, like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-user-is-an-administrative-user), only check if the user is an admin on the currently executing machine.

```vb
Dim user As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
Dim principal As New WindowsPrincipal(user)
Dim isAdmin As Boolean = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

Comment: aside: wouldn't it be easier to just handle the occasional failure? Rather than execute some WMI calls against the target machine and parse the rights of that user.

This just strikes me as the same type of question as "how can I tell if I can write to a file?" the answer is, "do it, and handle errors"

Comment: I'm of the opinion that it's typically best to handle easily avoidable errors before they occur.  I'd rather not incur the cost of handeling an exception for almost every server in a long list of servers if I can check priveleges ahead of time.  Also, the way I currently have it structured I can save permission information temporarily in my server list so it won't need to make the call twice to check.  It's harder to do that in a catch block where any number of issues beside permissions could be at hand.

Comment: @Kyle: The cost of an exception is several orders of magnitude cheaper than a single network call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt.

The following function will return whether or not a user belongs to a particular user group (in my case `"Administrators"`) on any machine.

```vb
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Public Shared Function IsMemberOfGroup(userName As String, machineName As String, memberGroup as String) As Boolean
    Dim isMember As Boolean = False
    Using rootContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName), _
          grp As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, memberGroup), _
          usr As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName)
        If grp IsNot Nothing AndAlso usr IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Check if the user is a member of the group.
            isMember = grp.GetMembers(True).Contains(usr)
        Else
            isMember = False
        End If
    End Using
    Return isMember
End Function
```

The caveat is that the user running the method has to be an admin in order to have rights to this information set in `PrincipalContext`.  I was hoping that the application would be able to determine if the user running the application is an admin.

The only way to make this super helpful is to call it and see if it came up with "Access Denied", similar to [hometoast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2009/hometoast) already suggested, but this still doesn't feel super "clean"