# Installer Permissions Detection

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissions

I need some information regarding permissions/installers.

I am currently on a project where we need to have an installer for our application. The program is compatible with Windows XP+ so XP, Vista, 7 & 8. What I need to be able to do is detect whether the current user has permissions to be able to install our application.

I've found a couple of posts on the matter but none of them seem to give me the definitive answer I want/need.

As for our Architecture it is as follows:

We have a 'click once' application that contains a C++ application, a .NET 2.0 'Windows Application' & a .NET 4.0 'Windows Application' - the C++ application is fairly simple it basically just detects the version of .NET they have installed and delegates off to that Windows Application. Each of those Windows Applications are essentially the same - they basically do a Connection Speed check and if that passes it downloads and runs the appropriate MSI Installer for our Software.

The user obviously needs to be able to have permissions to be able to install our application which we need to add detection in somewhere along this chain (either around the speed check in the windows application or part of the MSI installer I'm not sure - this is what I need people's help with).

What is the best way to go about doing this and how?

From what I can tell they'll be some complexities around UAC (whether it's on, off & whether they are local admin's, domain admins or just a regular user, also if they are a domain user and not currently on the network). They'll also be some other complexities as we'll also need to compensate for XP which doesn't have UAC (in fact I'm not sure at all how to detect it for XP).

From what I've seen online there's some options doing it in code such as this: [In .NET/C# test if process has administrative privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-user-is-an-administrative-user)

There's also some other options around a Manifest such as: [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) - would a manifest type approach work on XP?

I've got a few options along this pipeline with where to add this in so what I'm looking for from the community is information on where/how to do this for all my requirements.

Any help that anyone could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on the best practice, but if you wanted to detect if a user has admin rights either by their account being in the Administrator group or if they have the ability to escalate to that role via UAC, have a look at the MSDN code sample for Self Escalation: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3/sourcecode?fileId=21729&pathId=1041468146

That example has a method MainForm.IsUserInAdminGroup() that looks at either the current user's token or their escalation token:

```
/// <summary> 
/// The function checks whether the primary access token of the process belongs  
/// to user account that is a member of the local Administrators group, even if  
/// it currently is not elevated. 
/// </summary> 
/// <returns> 
/// Returns true if the primary access token of the process belongs to user  
/// account that is a member of the local Administrators group. Returns false  
/// if the token does not. 
/// </returns> 
/// <exception cref="System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"> 
/// When any native Windows API call fails, the function throws a Win32Exception  
/// with the last error code. 
/// </exception> 
internal bool IsUserInAdminGroup() 
{ 
    bool fInAdminGroup = false; 
    SafeTokenHandle hToken = null; 
    SafeTokenHandle hTokenToCheck = null; 
    IntPtr pElevationType = IntPtr.Zero; 
    IntPtr pLinkedToken = IntPtr.Zero; 
    int cbSize = 0; 

    try 
    { 
        // Open the access token of the current process for query and duplicate. 
        if (!NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, 
            NativeMethods.TOKEN_QUERY | NativeMethods.TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out hToken)) 
        { 
            throw new Win32Exception(); 
        } 

        // Determine whether system is running Windows Vista or later operating  
        // systems (major version >= 6) because they support linked tokens, but  
        // previous versions (major version < 6) do not. 
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) 
        { 
            // Running Windows Vista or later (major version >= 6).  
            // Determine token type: limited, elevated, or default.  

            // Allocate a buffer for the elevation type information. 
            cbSize = sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE); 
            pElevationType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbSize); 
            if (pElevationType == IntPtr.Zero) 
            { 
                throw new Win32Exception(); 
            } 

            // Retrieve token elevation type information. 
            if (!NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken,  
                TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenElevationType, pElevationType, 
                cbSize, out cbSize)) 
            { 
                throw new Win32Exception(); 
            } 

            // Marshal the TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE enum from native to .NET. 
            TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE elevType = (TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE) 
                Marshal.ReadInt32(pElevationType); 

            // If limited, get the linked elevated token for further check. 
            if (elevType == TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeLimited) 
            { 
                // Allocate a buffer for the linked token. 
                cbSize = IntPtr.Size; 
                pLinkedToken = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbSize); 
                if (pLinkedToken == IntPtr.Zero) 
                { 
                    throw new Win32Exception(); 
                } 

                // Get the linked token. 
                if (!NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken, 
                    TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenLinkedToken, pLinkedToken, 
                    cbSize, out cbSize)) 
                { 
                    throw new Win32Exception(); 
                } 

                // Marshal the linked token value from native to .NET. 
                IntPtr hLinkedToken = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pLinkedToken); 
                hTokenToCheck = new SafeTokenHandle(hLinkedToken); 
            } 
        } 

        // CheckTokenMembership requires an impersonation token. If we just got  
        // a linked token, it already is an impersonation token.  If we did not  
        // get a linked token, duplicate the original into an impersonation  
        // token for CheckTokenMembership. 
        if (hTokenToCheck == null) 
        { 
            if (!NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(hToken, 
                SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, 
                out hTokenToCheck)) 
            { 
                throw new Win32Exception(); 
            } 
        } 

        // Check if the token to be checked contains admin SID. 
        WindowsIdentity id = new WindowsIdentity(hTokenToCheck.DangerousGetHandle()); 
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(id); 
        fInAdminGroup = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        // Centralized cleanup for all allocated resources.  
        if (hToken != null) 
        { 
            hToken.Close(); 
            hToken = null; 
        } 
        if (hTokenToCheck != null) 
        { 
            hTokenToCheck.Close(); 
            hTokenToCheck = null; 
        } 
        if (pElevationType != IntPtr.Zero) 
        { 
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pElevationType); 
            pElevationType = IntPtr.Zero; 
        } 
        if (pLinkedToken != IntPtr.Zero) 
        { 
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLinkedToken); 
            pLinkedToken = IntPtr.Zero; 
        } 
    } 

    return fInAdminGroup; 
}
```