# Is it possible to require administrator rights when opening second form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know you can create a manifest file to specify access level administrator for the whole application. But is it possible to only require it for a specific form?

Answer (score 1):

Elevation is a property of the process. All of your forms execute in the same process. It makes no sense to ask how to execute different forms in the same process with different privileges. That is just meaningless.

So, if you need part of your application to run without elevation, and part of it to run elevated, then you need two processes. There's no alternative.

The clean way to achieve this though is to arrange for the elevated part of the application to be available through an out of process COM server. That way you can use the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to elevate that part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

[This code allows you to test if a user is admin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-user-is-an-administrative-user) You would need to call this code when ever you created the Form window you wished to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure something like that exist. I've done something similar manually by restarting the application.

Start your application without administrator access. When user does something which requires administrator access, See if application is running as administrator(It won't be, as we started normally)? If no, save the program state and restart the application with verb = "runas" and commdandline indicating what action to take.

When application is restarted, assuming user have provided administrator access via UAC. Handle the commandline, restore the saved program state and navigate the user to the place where he left.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this sample [UAC self-elevation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3)

This example demonstrates how to check the privilege level of the current process, and how to self-elevate the process by giving explicit consent with the Consent UI.