# How to prevent my program from running in a non-administrator account that has UAC turned off?

Tags: c#

I'm using this line in the app.manifest in order to raise an UAC prompt that demands administrative privileges in order for my program to run:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

It works. However, I found out that if the program is executed in a standard user account *and* UAC is turned-off, the program still runs - without administrative privileges -.

What I want, is to prevent it from running in this scenario. Instead, it should give a message like: "Sorry, this program requires administrative privileges to run". And then it should close itself.

Most questions I found here in SO, are about how to elevate an application when UAC is turned off. That's not what I'm searching.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-process-has-administrative-privileges

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if your user is administrator with this:

```
if (!WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
{
    // show messagebox "Sorry, this program requires administrative privileges to run"
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole)' I think that WindowsPrincipal class must be instantiated? That's what happens here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089046/in-net-c-test-if-process-has-administrative-privileges